# Accuracy of Chebyshev vs Legendre Polynomials in function approximation

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

I am trying to figure out if Chebyshev polynomials are preferred over Legendre polynomials in function approximation. I read on several sources that Chebyshev Polynomials yield a better and more accurate solution.

I read [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_most_frequently_used_orthogonal_polynomial_over-1_1):

> in almost all computational cases it is easier to solve a problem using the Legendre polynomials than the Chebyshev polynomials because the Legendre polynomial has the weight function w(x)=1; for example in the least-squares and for the Gaussian Quadratures.

[here:](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3314/930d57588d227b1affc7b81b58ddec43a4bb.pdf)

> ...it is observed that Chebyshev series gives a better approximation, ...

and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042706003177)

> Chebyshev series are accurate approximations only on the canonical interval . As explained in [6], the error grows exponentially fast as x moves from this interval for either real or complex x. Consequently, the only roots of interest are those that either lie on the canonical interval or are extremely close.

I tried this myself, trying to approximate $x^3 - \frac{x^4}{2} + \frac{x^5}{3} - \frac{x^6}{4}$ . As can be seen, the Chebyshev Polynomials provide a "perfect" fit.

[image]

My question is thus, why do Chebyshev Polynomials provide better approximations?

Comment: I think something might be wrong with your Legendre approximation, you're trying to fit a 6th degree polynomial with a 6th degree polynomial, it should be perfect.  Chebyshev polynomials have a number of advantages, not least of which is they can be fit via a FFT.  Trefethen's a good place to read more : https://www.chebfun.org/docs/guide/guide04.html

Comment: Thank you, will look into the Legendre not being a perfect fit and the link suggested.